# Paypal shopping cart - Setting database value when successfully completed transaction

Tags: php, html, paypal, transactions

I've got a question about the PayPal transaction system. I try to implement a paypal shopping cart in my website. But what I want to do is I want to have like "PrePaid credits" on my website. So when the transaction successfully processed. A database value will change given the credits the user wanted to buy.

I dont have a idea on what to search for. I only know standard php. Not any modification such as paypal. So can anyone give me a code/website where I can find some usefull code?

Thank you!

PS: If you have any suggestions on the post to make it even clearer please comment.

Comment: This is probably what you want : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/ Instead of sending an email, you could just run an `UPDATE` query on the DB, and add the credits to the users account. Do you already have a credits field in the user accounts table?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification), so a user would click 'Purchase x credits' on your site (you would have a custom field with the user's ID, it would then take them to PayPal via custom form you put together, that form has a return URL which after the payment has been successfully made, would return them to that URL, and you would make that success return URL update your database with the details.

So on a successful return from PayPal, your page would update the database with the custom value (User ID) we initially passed in the form along with the amount of credits they purchase (this can be passed via custom value OR you could just use PayPal's callback information returned with the query (it'll be posted to your page from PayPal I believe).

[PayPal Sample Code](https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples)

[Getting Started with the PayPal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)

[Nettuts - Using PayPal's Instant Payment Notification](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/)